# Как отправить уведомление 1 раз, при нескольких запусках скрипта

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт который запускается раз в несколько минут и шлет уведомления. Как сделать что бы он слал только 1 раз и не спамил)
Немного почитав советуют сохранять состояние в файл. Как это реализовать? Моего опыта маловато в этом)

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=`wget -q -O redirect http://ссылка && cat ./redirect | grep текст | wc -l`
echo $RESULT >> /usr/local/bin/log.log

if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ];then curl ссылка

fi
```

Comment: логичный ответ: запускайте только один раз.

Comment: О спасибо большое за такой совет... Но, нет.

Comment: если не подходит логичный ответ, то, вероятно, вам стоит уточнить (в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]), что именно вам требуется.

Comment: вы вероятно хотите *больше* одного уведомления посылать. По одному на каждое новое событие (что такое новое событие — это уже от задачи зависит, за вас никто не скажет). Если вы уверены, что за всю жизнь ровно одно уведомление хотите отправить, то просто не запускайте скрипт после получения уведомления.

Comment: Скрипт в автозапуске каждые 10 минут, я хочу что бы он мне не присылал каждые 10 минут вывод, а брал вывод из лог файла (добавил в скрипт) и присылал мне вывод только если поменялось значение с 1 на 0 и наоборот

Comment: @RusNurOff  информацию необходимую для ответа следует в сам вопрос помещать. Разбейте задачу на более простые шаги: получите обновление, прочитайте последнюю строчку, сравните, сохраните в файл. Если какой-то шаг не ясно как делать, то задайте отдельный вопрос. К примеру, «как прочитать последнюю строчку из файла» — таким образом большему кругу людей ответы могут помочь.

Comment: Я так понял вы решили решать задачу самыми не unixовыми методами: зачем вам файл, если вы только количество совпадений с шаблоном считаете? Useless use of cat — это такой мем, погуглите, чтобы больше так не делать. $() лучше обратных кавычек.